# Why is any element in $rad(kG)$ nilpotnet?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, representation-theory

I am reading proof of Brauer's theorem and I came across this result that any element of $rad(kG)$ is nilpotent. Why is this true?
$rad$ is Jacobson radical and $kG$ is group algebra over field $k$. Further $G$ is finite and $k$ is splitting field of $G$.

Comment: It's true for any Artinian ring.

Comment: I knew the result for commutative rings.

Comment: Pretty much the same argument works for non-commutative rings.